# How to prevent users from seeing my files, only me, using .htaccess?

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I have a .json file, and I'm using ajax to get the data, but I would like no one to be able to see the file, nor use it.

**This doesn't work, because why not even i can access with ajax**

```
<Files "*.json">
      Order Deny, Allow
      deny from all
      allow from localhost
</Files>
```

I wish that no one could see the file or use it, only my website, and anyone who accesses my website can't see it too

Comment: What does "only my website" actually mean? Sounds like you make an ajax request to fetch the data which is then processed/used on the client side. So the file has to be accessible, no way around that. And if that is the case, then you cannot somehow magically prevent someone on the client side to see that data. Simply because you have no control of the client side. In other words: you publish data (json format). You cannot somehow not publish it at the same time.

Comment: What you could do is use some form of access token which is validated when the data is requested. You could implement such validation in a routing script on the server side and hand out an individual token valid for a short period of time each time a client opens a session. That prevents people from simply requesting the file via web browser. But obviously they can use the token when extracting it from your ajax preparing logic. So there is no robust solution.

Comment: I ask a question back to help you decide what you want to do: _why_ do you want to limit access to that file? You initially publish it since you want to use it in the ajax request. So you want to publish the data to the clients. Then how come you want to restrict that access again? Doesn't that contradict itself? What is it that you want to achieve here?